# Getting a single element from LINQuery?

Tags: c#, linq

So I'm new to using LINQ and it seems really useful but I am having some trouble getting the value from a query.

This is my original code that works but I want to replace with LINQ:

```
foreach (LocationModel loc in locationList)
{
    if (loc.Name.Equals(location, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        locationId = loc.Id;
        break;
    }
}
```

This is the LINQ I wrote for doing the same thing:

```
var matchQuery = from loc in locationList
                 where loc.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == location.ToLowerInvariant()
                 select loc.Id;
```

Now how do I actially get the int Id from matchQuery?

Comment: [First()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) forat least one element, [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault(v=vs.100).aspx) for 0 or n, [Single()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single(v=vs.100).aspx) for 1 result and finally [SingleOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault(v=vs.100).aspx) for 0 or 1

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the first item then use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
 var id = (from loc in locationList
           where loc.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == location.ToLowerInvariant()
           select loc.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or in method syntax:

```
var id = locationList.FirstOrDefault(loc => loc.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == location.ToLowerInvariant())?.Id;
```

Comment: Awesome!

Is any of your methods preferred? Or are they in practice the same?

Comment: @knuffemuffe - you can check them performance wise they should operate the same. IMO go for the second as in this specific case it is more readable

Comment: If you expect only one record, you can also use SingleOrDefault() instead of FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Alright, and here I though LINQ was easier to read. But I get you, less code is good. :)

Comment: @knuffemuffe - both are linq - one is query syntax the other method syntax

Comment: @knuffemuffe - Did this answer help you solve the problem? If so please consider marking it as solved

Comment: @knuffemuffe: LINQ (query syntax) being easier to read is arguable (and subjective). I personally really dislike the query syntax and much prefer the method syntax. To me, the query syntax is too-similar-but-also-too-different from SQL, to a point where my brain keeps trying to use normal SQL syntax. The order of operations in query syntax really irks me. But performance wise, they should be the same (I would assume that any pedantic difference is negligible)